# Why is docker-compose running the same command and using the wrong Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've got a simple Node / React project. I'm trying to use Docker to create two containers, one for the server, and one for the client, each with their own `Dockerfile` in the appropriate directory.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  client:
    image: node:14.15-buster
    build:
      context: ./src
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.client
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
      - '45799:45799'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    tty: true

  server:
    image: node:14.15-buster
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.server
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
    tty: true

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis
    ports:
      - '6379'
```

`src/Dockerfile.client`

```
FROM node:14.15-buster

# also the directory you land in on ssh
WORKDIR /app

CMD cd /app && \
  yarn && \
  yarn start:client
```

`server/Dockerfile.server`

```
FROM node:14.15-buster

# also the directory you land in on ssh
WORKDIR /app

CMD cd /app && \
  yarn && \
  yarn start:server
```

After building and starting the containers, both containers run the same command, seemingly at random. Either both run `yarn start:server` or `yarn start:client`. The logs clearly detail duplicate startup commands and ports being used. Requests to either port 3000 (client) or 3001 (server) confirm that the same one is being used in both containers. If I change the command in both `Dockerfile`s to echo the respective filename (`Dockerfile.server!` or `Dockerfile.client!`), startup reveals only one `Dockerfile` being used for both containers. I am also running the latest version of Docker on Mac.

What is causing `docker-compose` to use the same `Dockerfile` for both containers?

Answer (score 0):

After a lengthy and painful bout of troubleshooting, I narrowed the issue down to duplicate image references. `image: node:14.15-buster` for each service in `docker-compose.yml` and `FROM node:14.15-buster` in each `Dockerfile`.

Why this would cause this behavior is unclear, but after removing the image references in `docker-compose.yml` and rebuilding / restarting, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `docker-compose build` with both `image` and `build` properties set on a service, it will build an image according to the `build` property and then tag the image according to the `image` property.

In your case, you have two services building different images and tagging them with the same tag `node:14.15-buster`. One will overwrite the other.

This probably has the additional unintended consequence of causing your next image to be built on top of the previously built image instead of the true `node:14.15-buster`.

Then when you start the service, both containers will use the image tagged `node:14.15-buster`.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build):

> If you specify image as well as build, then Compose names the built image with the webapp and optional tag specified in image